# Reload current page and upload a persistent variable in Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

All my view in my current project extend from a general index view which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TITLE</title>
    </head>
    {{ stylesheet_link("css/base.css") }}
    {{ stylesheet_link("css/layout.css") }}
    {{ stylesheet_link("css/skeleton.css") }}
    {{ stylesheet_link("css/main.css") }}
    {{ stylesheet }}
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="one columns">
               <!-- HERE IS THE NAV-BAR -->
            </div>

            <div class="sixteen columns">
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div class="one column offset-by-thirteen"><a href="#">{{ english }}</a></div>
            <div class="one column"><a href="#">{{ french }}</a></div>
            <div class="one column"><a href="#">{{ chinese }}</a></div>
        </div>
        {{ content() }}
    </body>
</html>
```

So this general index is just providing a navigation bar and 3 links (english, french, chinese).

The controller looks like the following:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class ControllerBase extends Controller
{

    protected function beforeExecuteRoute($dispatcher) 
    {

        $default_language = "en";

        if (!isset($this->persistent->lang)) {
            $this->persistent->lang = $default_language;
        }

        // PROVIDING DATA HERE SUCH LIKE PICTURES
    }

    protected function afterExecuteRoute($dispatcher) 
    {

        $this->view->url = $this->dispatcher->getControllerName() . "/" . $this->dispatcher->getActionName() . "/" . $this->dispatcher->getParams();

    }
}
```

In the protected function I try to get the current url.

My goal is to be able to change language by reloading the current url and updating a persistent variable:

```
$this->persistent->lang
```

(so by providing a parameter while reloading the page for example), I don't want to load the home page but the current page.

In my provided code, I am trying to get the desired url by calling:

```
$this->dispatcher->getControllerName() . "/" . $this->dispatcher->getActionName() . "/" . $this->dispatcher->getParams();
```

But the `getParams()` just give me a empty array...

For instance, I have a controller `AboutController`, which have the following action:

```
resumeAction($author)
```

So the url for this page is:

```
http://localhost/website/about/resume/bob
```

But the variable `url` defined in my `BaseController` give me `about/resume/Array` and not `about/resume/bob`.

How to get the desired path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the variable `url` defined in my `BaseController` give me
>   `about/resume/Array` and not `about/resume/bob`.

When you see `Array` show up it means that the variable is an array & you should access it as such. So `$this->dispatcher->getParams()` is a function that returns an array. Now you need to act on it. You can check it’s contents like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->dispatcher->getParams());
echo '</pre>';
```

And then you can view additional data by doing this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->dispatcher->getParam('[name of the param here]'));
echo '</pre>';
```

And just change `[name of the param here]` to the actual name of the parameter you would like to access.

More details on getting parameters up on [the official Phalcon documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/dispatching.html#getting-parameters).